# How to split a word using one character from that word using Javascript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a following string(a link to be more precise):

`/plans/p`

Now, I want to split it with delimiter `/p`. Now, as you can see there's two `/p`. However, I want to separate it with the second `/p`. That `/p` will always have one character and i.e. `p`.

How is it possible using regex to get something like: `["/plans", ""]`

I tried the following:

`str.split(/p/i)`

Comment: `str.split('/p')` or `str.split(/\/p/)`

Comment: If that `p` must be a whole word, use `.split(/\/p\b/i)`. If that string is at the end, use `.split(/\/p$/i)`

Comment: Thank you so much!